# How to use Ant tool to build project in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ant

In the documentation for implementing In-App Billing, I am told to do this: "Put the AIDL file into your project and use the Ant tool to build your project so that the IInAppBillingService.java file gets generated.". I don't know what they meant by "use the Ant tool to build your project".

Comment: Provide appropriate build.xml from project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing actual build.xml file, I can't know for sure, but does running `ant` in the project directory work (project directory must contain `build.xml` file)?